# could not get data from file by ajax with jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I use the sample here:https://datatables.net/examples/styling/jqueryUI.html

Below is my html and jquery code

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-dataTables.css">
  
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="jquery-dataTables.js"></script>
  <script>
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/test.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the structure of my file

[image]

But it couldn't load data into datatable, anyone can help?

Edit (Attach my test data): this data is used for

"data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1562"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6224"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cara Stevens",
      "position": "Sales Assistant",
      "salary": "$145,600",
      "start_date": "2011/12/06",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "3990"
    },
    {
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    }
  ]

Thanks

Comment: how does the content of `test.txt` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you used example `test.txt` file from [Datatables ajax simple example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html), but defined columns as in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/object_data.html). The problem is `test.txt` file doesn't have columns, your datatable expecting. So there are two ways to fix it:
Do not define columns in datatable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/test.txt"
    } );
} );
```

Or change your `test.txt` file to match columns, like:

```
"data": [
{
  "name": "Airi",
  "position": "Accountant",
  "office": "Tokyo",
  "extn": "...",
  "start_date": "28th Nov 08",
  "salary": "$162,700"
},...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but both of the solutions don't work. :(

Comment: Could you provide `test.txt` content, it would be easier to help